# Jersey - JsonFormatException - JAXB - GET returns okay - PUT parse throws error

Tags: java, jaxb, intellij-idea, jersey

Okay so I have a little issue here.

I have the following class annotated with JAXB: 
https://github.com/gaborbernat/fs_viewer/blob/master/fs_data/src/net.primeranks.fs_data/User.java

Then I have a Jersey resource to handle the GET/PUT stuff:
https://github.com/gaborbernat/fs_viewer/blob/master/fs_primeranks_server/src/net/primeranks/fs_server/ResourceUser.java

Now my problem is that the GET part works great. And for example a valid GET output may be this: https://github.com/gaborbernat/fs_viewer/blob/master/fs_primeranks_server/rsc/json_2_yet_sas.txt

However if I specify the same text as PUT parameter, bang an error comes up. Here's my request (using IntelliJ).
![I pass the text file back as PUT content.][1]

I turned on detailed logging on the App server so I can see what's up. Here's the result:

```
    May 1, 2012 8:03:45 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
    FINE: Mapped exception to response: 400 (Bad Request)
    javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonFormatException: Unexpected character: - (line: 1, column: 1)
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider.readFrom(JSONJAXBElementProvider.java:128)
...
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonFormatException: Unexpected character: - (line: 1, column: 1)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonLexer.yylex(JsonLexer.java:662)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.nextToken(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.readNext(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.readNext(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:178)
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmCiE.png`enter code here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the IntelliJ Idea will upload the file itself and not its content.
Tried it out with the Firefox restclient extension and seems to work just fine.